# Display XML as response in PHP with eBay API

Tags: php, xml, parsing, ebay-api

Following [tutorial](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_PHP_XML_XML/GettingStarted_PHP_XML_XML.html#step3) shows how to display data as HTML based on that I just need to show response of XML as opposed to parsing it. I have tried to find solution but didn't have any luck. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php

$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
$query = 'iphone';                  // Supply your own query keywords as needed

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords POST call
// Load the call and capture the response returned by the eBay API
// The constructCallAndGetResponse function is defined below
$resp = simplexml_load_string(constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query));

// Check to see if the call was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
$results = '';  // Initialize the $results variable

// Parse the desired information from the response
foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
$link  = $item->viewItemURL;
$title = $item->title;

// Build the desired HTML code for each searchResult.item node and append it to $results
$results .= "<tr><td><img src=\"$pic\"></td><td><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></td></tr>";
 }
}
else {  // If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
  $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful";
  $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}

function constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query) {
global $xmlrequest;

// Create the XML request to be POSTed
$xmlrequest  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
$xmlrequest .= "<findItemsByKeywordsRequest                  
xmlns=\"http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services\">\n";
$xmlrequest .= "<keywords>";
$xmlrequest .= $query;
$xmlrequest .= "</keywords>\n";
$xmlrequest .= "<paginationInput>\n 
<entriesPerPage>3</entriesPerPage>\n</paginationInput>\n";
$xmlrequest .= "</findItemsByKeywordsRequest>";

// Set up the HTTP headers
$headers = array(
'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findItemsByKeywords',
'X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.3.0',
'X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: XML',
'X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID: EBAY-GB',
'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: ******',
'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8',
);

$session  = curl_init($endpoint);                       // create a curl session
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);              // POST request type
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    // set headers using $headers
 array
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlrequest); // set the body of the POST
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    //

$responsexml = curl_exec($session);                     // send the request
curl_close($session);                                   // close the session
return $responsexml;                                    // returns a string


}  // End of constructPostCallAndGetResponse function
?>
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far? Questions here should show some substantial prior effort or some non-working code, so respondents have something to work with. Unfortunately, this code has neither, so currently is likely to be closed.

Comment: The tutorial shows the code parsing the xml to html. I jus want it to show the xml node tree.

Comment: OK. Nevertheless, please _try_ first - have you got the example working already?

Comment: I have the example working fine. Ive tried it without including the code to parse the data to HTML but then it doesn't display anything.

Comment: OK, great. Let's see the code you have, "without including the code to parse the data to HTML" (edit it into your question please). My guess is that you need to grab the result of `constructPostCallAndGetResponse()` and print that to the screen, probably in `htmlentities()` so you can see the angle brackets.

Comment: Posted the code I have from the tutorial. It includes constructPostCallAndGetResponse(). Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this (wrapped for clarity):

```
$resp = simplexml_load_string(
    constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query)
);
```

to this:

```
$xmlString = constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query);
$resp = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
// Now you have your raw XML to play with
echo htmlentities($xmlString);
// The XML document $resp is available too, if you wish to do
// something with that
```

The original feeds the XML response immediately into an XML parser, and creates an XML object with it (look up SimpleXML in the PHP manual for details). Here, we've split the two calls up, so the XML string is now saved in an intermediate variable.

Comment: That has solved my problem. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Can the XML returned be saved to an XML file on the server?